# How to access nested XML

Tags: php, xml, foreach

Hi I'm using an XML feed and I need to access a loop inside an XML loop.

Basically the xml I have is this:

```
<properties>
    <property>
        <images>
            <image modified="2012-04-03 19:20:16">http://image.url/</image>
            <image modified="2012-04-03 19:20:16">http://image.url/</image>
            <image modified="2012-04-03 19:20:16">http://image.url/</image>
            <image modified="2012-04-03 19:20:16">http://image.url/</image>
            <image modified="2012-04-03 19:20:16">http://image.url/</image>
            <image modified="2012-04-03 19:20:16">http://image.url/</image>
        </images>
    </property>
</properties>
```

I have this loop:

```
foreach($xml->property as $property) {
    foreach($property->images->image as $key => $value) {
        print_r($value);
    }
}
```

But the $value is returning  [@attributes] => Array ( [modified] => 2013-10-03 11:53:47

I want the http://image.url/ to be returned.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the value to string like:

```
foreach($xml->property as $property) {
    foreach($property->images->image as $img) {
        $value = (string) $img;
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working great when I echo it but for some reason when I put it in the MySQL query to set it into the database it puts in 0. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Got it! Thanks, it was a problem with Wordpress. Anyway thanks!